# Hide and move an element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know how to use jquery to hide an element (in this case an image in the blue div), but on click I would also like it to reappear, in the green div (somewhere else on the page). Maybe even go back to the blue div after I click it when It is in the green div. How can I do that?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cmfZX/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use event delegation to make this easy:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bottom-div").on("click","img",function(){
        $(this).appendTo("#top-div"); 
    });
    $("#top-div").on("click","img",function(){
        $(this).appendTo("#bottom-div"); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cmfZX/4/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `append` not `hide`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmfZX/3/

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
      if($(this).closest("#top-div").length > 0) {
          //Move to bottom Div
          $("#bottom-div").append(this);
      } else {
          $("#top-div").append(this);          
      }
    //$(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fWKpK/)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
  $("img").click(function(){
    var clonedImg = $(this).clone();
    $(this).hide();
    $('#top-div').append(clonedImg);     
  });
    
});
```

From the jQuery Docs:

http://api.jquery.com/clone 
http://api.jquery.com/append

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
    $(this).appendTo("#top-div");
  });
});
```